# Numerical computation of magnetic Euler-Heisenberg integral

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration, numerics

The Euler-Heisenberg action describes non-linear interactions of electromagnetic fields. The case I am interested in corresponds to the ideal MHD limit (with vanishing electric field), where the relevant integral can be written as something like (Equation 5 from [Gravejat et al. 2018](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0021782417301095))

$$ L(B) = \frac{1}{8 \pi^2} \int^{\infty}_{0} ds \frac {e^{-s m^2}} {s^3} \left( e s B \coth (e s B)  - 1 - \frac {e^2 s^2 B^2} {3} \right),$$

for constants $e$ and $m$.

This integral has well-known asymptotic results in the weak-field ($B \rightarrow 0$) or strong-field ($B \rightarrow \infty$) limits, but I am interested in more generally evaluating this numerically using Mathematica to consider the whole range.

Although I have tried looking through the literature, I have not been able to find someone plotting this actual integral as a function of $B$, which is what I am really after. Naively trying to just use NIntegrate gives me either zero or complaints because of the exponential suppression, as does truncating the domain to something finite and using a trapezodial or similar method, and I am not sure what else I could try. Can Mathematica handle integrals such as this?

Comment: What did you try so far? Please provide Mathematica code and range of parameters !

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First, we can note that the combination $e B$ always appears together, thus we can set $e=1$ and work in appropriately rescaled units.

Then, NIntegrate can (for the most part) do the integrations numerically

```
L[B_, e_, m_] := 
1/(8 Pi^2) NIntegrate[Exp[-s m^2]/s^3 (e s B Coth[e s B] - 1 - (e^2 s^2 B^2)/3), {s,0,\[Infinity]}, MaxRecursion -> 30, WorkingPrecision -> 30]
```

Then we run it for various values of $B$ (with $e=1$) and use a `ParallelTable` to speed things up:

```
LaunchKernels[8];
data\[Ellipsis]m\[Ellipsis]0\[Ellipsis]01 = 
  ParallelTable[{B, L[B, 1, 1/100]}, {B, 1/10, 10, 1/10}];
data\[Ellipsis]m\[Ellipsis]0\[Ellipsis]1 = 
  ParallelTable[{B, L[B, 1, 1/10]}, {B, 1/10, 10, 1/10}];
data\[Ellipsis]m1 = 
  ParallelTable[{B, L[B, 1, 1]}, {B, 1/10, 10, 1/10}];
data\[Ellipsis]m10 = 
  ParallelTable[{B, L[B, 1, 10]}, {B, 1/10, 10, 1/10}];
data\[Ellipsis]m100 = 
  ParallelTable[{B, L[B, 1, 100]}, {B, 1/10, 10, 1/10}];
```

Then plotting it gives:

```
ListLogLogPlot[{data\[Ellipsis]m\[Ellipsis]0\[Ellipsis]01, 
data\[Ellipsis]m\[Ellipsis]0\[Ellipsis]1,data\[Ellipsis]m1, data\[Ellipsis]m10, data\[Ellipsis]m100} // Abs, PlotLegends -> {"m=0.01", "m=0.1", "m=1", "m=10", "m=100"},Frame -> True, FrameStyle -> Black, FrameLabel -> {"e B", "|L|"}, Joined -> True, BaseStyle -> FontSize -> 12]
```

[image]

It may also be possible to find the asymptotic limits for high/low masses $m$ (the only other free parameter of the problem).